# Menu items not rendering with IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, mozilla

If I render below HTML code in Mozilla Firefox its fine. If render same in IE(9.0.8112) its not displaying my menu items. How to fix this for IE (which is coming by default with windows 7)?

**CSS**

```
ul#nav {margin: 0 0 0 10px;}
ul.drop a { display:block; color: #fff; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13px;     text-decoration: none;}
ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #fff; background: #555; color: #fff;}
ul.drop { position: relative; z-index: 597; float: left; }
ul.drop li { float: left; line-height: 1.3em; vertical-align: middle; zoom: 1; padding: 5px 40px; }
ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover { position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default; background: #1e7c9a; }
ul.drop ul { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598; width: 195px; background: #555; border: 1px solid #fff; }
ul.drop ul li { float: none; }
ul.drop ul ul { top: -2px; left: 100%; }
ul.drop li:hover > ul { visibility: visible }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav" class="drop">

   <li>Projects
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">All Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Proj Details</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Dailies
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/addTask/fillTask/">Add Task</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Add Status</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Add Data
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/addProjHtml/">Add Proj</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Add Assets</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Add Scenes</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: Works fine for me in IE9 on windows 8 - http://jsfiddle.net/P83df/

Comment: it is working fine in windows 7 also.

Comment: I have created a drop down menu. On mouse over the menu list its child. But in IE the childs did not display when I over the mouse on the menu.